# json objects using volley with GET request are not working

Tags: php, android, json

I want to retrieve data from `mysql` using `GET` request based on specific id and it gives error

**here is my php code:**

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$veery_id= $_GET['veery_id'];
require_once('dbConnect.php');  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reply_info WHERE veery_id='".$veery_id."'";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();  
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
 $result[] = $res;
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}
```

**Here is the response by testing on postman:**

> {"result":[{"reply_id":"1","reply_content":"first
>   reply","replier":"mesh","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-15
>   06:15:30"},{"reply_id":"2","reply_content":"second
>   reply","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-15
>   06:15:30"},{"reply_id":"4","reply_content":"hello from
>   postman2","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-15
>   06:15:30"},{"reply_id":"5","reply_content":"ifwifewds","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-22
>   04:55:53"},{"reply_id":"6","reply_content":"fsdhfdshuhusfdf","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-22
>   04:57:52"},{"reply_id":"7","reply_content":"jfdkjjfdfd","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-22
>   04:58:58"},{"reply_id":"9","reply_content":"huygygyg","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-22
>   06:38:59"},{"reply_id":"10","reply_content":"huygygyg","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-22
>   07:06:06"},{"reply_id":"12","reply_content":"hgdxdxf","replier":"mama","veery_id":"46","reply_datime":"2017-08-22
>   12:10:13"}]}

**Here is my java code**

```
 public void json_call() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(TAG_VEERYID,46);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_REPLY, jsonObject ,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //TODO print json array to test
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                JSONObject obj2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                ReplyItem dataSet = new ReplyItem();
                                dataSet.setReplier(obj2.getString(TAG_REPLIER));
                                dataSet.setReply_content(obj2.getString(TAG_REPLY));
                                dataSet.setReply_datime(obj2.getString(TAG_REPLYDATIME));
                                list.add(dataSet);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                },
                // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                //as a parameter
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(VeeryObj.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameters.put(TAG_VEERYID, id);
                return parameters;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonreq);
    }
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: any error in logcat?

Comment: Sorry, what's the error?

Comment: I guess your `id` value is wrong in your `getParams` method. I don't see where you have passed its value to your function. Maybe that's why you don't get what you expect.

Comment: getParams() won't be called for GET requests. Instead, just append the ID to the URL in query-string format (e.g.: http://my.example.com?id=my_id)

Comment: thanks it worked @Gil